# Running Excel.exe as Administrator is Much Slower than as a User

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, administrator, microsoft-excel-2019

On Windows 10, I have an autohotkey script that opens an Excel file. If my computer has been running for a while and I have the script run the Excel file as administrator, it takes over 60 seconds to open, while if I run it as a user, it opens up instantly. I noticed that if I restart or log on/log off when this happens, and try again, then both methods open up instantly.

It seems to be related to either my computer being turned on for a while or me having opened the Excel document as an administrator at least once before. I haven't been able to re-create the exact conditions that cause it because it seems random, but it's essentially guaranteed to happen after long enough because I've been noticing this for the past several months.

I'm not sure what could be causing it. Is there some process Excel is referencing that needs to be restarted as well? I'm sure there's a way to fix this without logging on and off again, but I don't know what additional process or service may need to be restarted. Restarting explorer.exe alone doesn't fix it.

I know what I provided isn't that detailed, but does anybody have any ideas as to what it could be? I have no plugins for Excel either. It is Excel Professional Plus 2019.

Comment: My own personal machine has my login userid as member of Administrators.  No issue with Excel. Make sure the Excel file is not open by the Standard User when you try to open with the Admin user.  I am using Office 365.

Comment: Is the use user account a local or a domain account?

Comment: It could just be a resource issue if the file is large - elevated processes will start a whole new session. What happens if you start excel as admin in safe mode like `excel /safe /r c:\path\to\file.xlsx`

Comment: @Robert, local: https://i.imgur.com/U49g6wV.png

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, I cannot test it right now because I restarted recently and it is fast again, but last time I tried it, it did not matter whether I was opening a large file or not; even just opening Excel by itself as administrator was slow. So it's unrelated to the particular file. But I will try safe mode next time it gets slow again and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like an ordinary local account. Then I would use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor to check what exactly Windows/Excel is doing in the delay.

Comment: @Robert, I'm not sure what other processes to look at, but when I limit it to Excel, I see this. The Thread Exit function was the only thing that showed up for Excel.exe prior to the actual application opening (in other words, while I was waiting). https://i.imgur.com/ucWUIB4.png What other processes should I be monitoring?